# Qgis: set "draw line inside polygon" using Python

Tags: python, qgis

This is a Qgis question. In the properties of a layer I want to activate "draw line only inside polygon" for a specific layer, but using Python. I don't want to use the GUI for it. Can this be done? if so, please advice!

I set the line width with the following code:

```
props['line_width'] = '1.0'
lineLayer = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleLine").createSymbolLayer(props)
```

If anyone has any idea how to check the "draw line only inside polygon" checkbox I would very much appreciate some help :).

Please see attached image.
[image: Qgis layer properties]